# MySQL if exists syntax

Tags: php, mysql, exists

Happy holidays, if you celebrate it.

I am trying to run the following query:

```
$query = SELECT WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE val1="someVal" and val2="someVal");
$result = mysql_query ($query)
print_r (mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

My goal is to create an associative array with only records from the matching row that have a value.

Am I using EXISTS in the wrong manner?

Comment: Just use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE val1="someVal" and val2="someVal"`??

Comment: Does that query return anything if nothing exists?

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start...

Comment: If you use `EXISTS` in the wrong manner ? Yes, there is no doubt. Read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html . But I don't think you need to use `EXISTS` for what you want. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE val1='someVal' and val2='someVal` should be enough.

Comment: mysql function are deprecated. You should switch to mysqli. From php 5.5.x onwards that piece of code won't work. http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: That's not how you run queries. Before you go down the `mysql_query` path, which is a bad plan considering it's obsolete and scheduled to be removed from PHP, spend a half hour and [learn to use PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) instead.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows($result) > 0` would be the quick way. or a proper `select count(*)`, fetch the count value, and compare that against 0

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. [SELECT * FROM table WHERE val1='someVal' and val2='someVal] returns me all rows, regardless of whether or not it has a value. I understand that this method is being deprecated... I just need to get it to omit columns that have no value. Is there a simple way to address this in the query?

Comment: The `WHERE` clause should prevent that from happening. Are you sure you're executing the right query? Have you tried running the query independently through either the `mysql` shell or database access tool?

Comment: sorry, I'm not explaining well. This query is returning an associative array which has all of my column names as indexes, even those which have no variable assigned to the index. I only want to return those columns names which have data and none of the column names that have no data.

Comment: i.e. instead of:
val1=>someVal
val2=>
val3=>someVal

I want to return:
val1=>someVal
val3=>someVal

Answer (score 0):

h2ooooooo is right, you don't need to use exits to select what you want here. Just a simple WHERE clause will do it. also I would single quote the values not double quote them for mysql syntax purposes. ie:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE val1='someVal' and val2='someVal'";

$result = mysql_query($query, $link);

print_r (mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

Comment: Sorry you are correct I just saw the issue, just a rush answer. I fixed it now.

Comment: You don't put a query in `mysql_fetch_assoc`, you put a resource. I see you've fixed it now.

Comment: I had just copied that piece from the original post and only edited teh query, I should take a better look next time. Thanks for catching it